# When sending email using javamail-android the body is attached as a text file

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am using the [JavaMail port for android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) to send emails without user intervention in the application. And I have noticed that some email systems does not display the email body correctly. When I send the email to Gmail the body is shown correctly, but when I send it to a company email (I am not exactly sure what it is using but it's a business mail from Telecom) the body is blank and instead there is an attachment of a text file ATT00001.txt with the content of body.

I am not an expert on the mail systems but from the code I use to set the body of email it seems like it is very similar to how you attach a file, and maybe that is why the body is not recognised as the body, but as an attachment.

The following code snippet is how the mail is created. The body and subjects are all initialised beforehand.

```
public synchronized void send() throws MessagingException {   
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    bodyPart.setText(body);
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    //message.setDataHandler(handler);
    multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
    message.setContent(multipart);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);  
    user = null;
    password = null;
    session = null;
}
```

If anyone knows how to get around this problem please help me! It is important for my application to show the body as the body. Also, if there is a better way of sending emails without user intervention, please suggest them too.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I tried using .setText() instead of BodyPart

```
message.setText(body);
```

This did not show the body at all from Gmail, and showed some weird string from the company mail

> ------=_Part_2_1079750440.1339556360521--

And while testing these, I created an email test activity which basically sends an email with a button click. After trying out a few things, I changed my class back to how it was (using BodyPart) and then it worked! It looks like the attachment was causing the problem and I think the way I'm attaching my files isn't correct.

```
public void addAttachment(File file) throws MessagingException {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);     
}
```

This addAttachment() function is called before send().

What is wrong with this?

EDIT:

In case anyone else is having the same issues, here's how I fixed it. The problem was fixed by setting the body before adding attachments. So instead of setting the body when sending, I set the body separately beforehand.

```
public void setBody(String body) throws MessagingException {
    BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    bodyPart.setText(body);
    multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
}

public synchronized void send() throws MessagingException {   
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setContent(multipart);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);  
    user = null;
    password = null;
    session = null;
}
```

So when I call the functions, I call setBody() first, then addAttachment(), then send(). 
Now the body of the email is shown as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just creating a plain text message without using a multipart.  Get rid of message.setContent(multipart) and use message.setText(body).

Comment: This doesn't work... Now the email doesn't show the body at all.

Comment: If all of this works with Gmail but fails with your company email, there's probably something wrong with your company email.  The JavaMail FAQ has tips for debugging.  Start there and post the results here and maybe we can help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Tried again and got some interesting results... I have edited my question.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.  Perhaps it's a problem with the javamail-android library that you're using.  Isn't there a way to use the real JavaMail jar file with android?  You might try getting your mail sending logic to work correctly from a simple desktop application before moving it to android.  That will also make it easier to debug any problems with configuration or with your mail server.

Comment: I have fixed the issue! It looks like the body has to be set before adding attachments. After I swapped the order of body and attachment it worked! Although you did not directly provide the solution thanks for advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with JavaMail API (and not just in android!), I faced the same issue and reordering (adding HTML part before attachment part) solved it.

**NOTE:** Also this issue can only be replicated if recipient's mailbox handles HTML differently (unlike MS Outlook for which it works perfectly).

```
BodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
BodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

message.setSubject("Some subject");
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("some-from-email@abc.org"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("some-recipient-email@abc.com"));

DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("./somedirectory" + File.separator + "filename.pdf");

attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));             
attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("filename.pdf");

htmlBodyPart.setContent("<html><body>Some HTML content</body></html>", "text/html");

//add HTML part before attachment 
multipart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);

message.setContent(multipart);
message.saveChanges();
```

Cheers!

**EDIT:** Updated the sample code and added more details for replication of the issue.